# Halcon - Variable iconic variable name

Tags: variables, variable-names, halcon, iconic

I have follwoing code:

```
for i:=0 to num_stripes by 1
        R := Row1 + 5*i
        gen_rectangle1(TransStripe, R,Column1,R+4, Column2)
        intersection(TransStripe, LabelSelcted, RegionIntersection)
        smallest_rectangle1(RegionIntersection, dummy, BeginCol, dummy, EndCol)
        inizio := BeginCol - 5
        fine := EndCol + 5
        area_center(RegionIntersection, dummy, centro_row, centro_col)
        gen_rectangle1(Str, R, inizio, R+4, fine)
        dev_set_color('red')
        dev_display(Str)
    endfor
```

In the last few lines, I create a rectangle named `Str`. Is there a way to create names on the fly, so that i have a variable for each rectangle? Str1, Str2 ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't a direct way to do this. There are a few workarounds:

**Concatenating objects:**

```
gen_empty_obj (EmptyObject)
for Index := 1 to 5 by 1
    gen_rectangle1 (Rectangle, 30, 20, 100, 200*Index)
    concat_obj (EmptyObject, Rectangle, EmptyObject)
endfor

** Selecting
select_obj (EmptyObject, ObjectSelected, 3)
```

**Using vectors (Halcon 12+ version required)**

```
for Index := 0 to 4 by 1
    gen_rectangle1 (Rectangle.at(Index), 30, 20, 100, 200*(Index+1))
endfor

** Selecting
Object := Rectangle.at(2)
```

It is also possible to use vectors as structures and adding multiple levels, where one level would be the names and other objects or values. If you'd like to read more about it, I wrote an article: https://subpixel.hr/halcon-is-like-a-box-of-chocolates/

Comment: thank you very much! how come in your first sample Rectangle is increased by adding objects and not overwritten?

Comment: There was a line missing:) It's fixed now

Comment: thank you! nice articles by the way.. have been reading some today.. :)